# Database failed to start: DB [database] 'v3.4.0' exited with status 'KILLED'. in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, user-defined-functions, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to build user defined procedures in Neo4j, that contains two procedures, reading and updating a full-text index, as shown in this link:

https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template

So, in order to do this, I clone this repository. And I am aware of project requirement dependency.

So, I packaged them into .jar files. And when I tried to deploy them to the database by dropping a jar file into the $NEO4J_HOME/plugins directory. And re-start the server to pick up new procedures, I got this error message:

```
Database failed to start: DB [database-b8e65583-1837-44c6-8a96-021c4d85fd90] 'v3.4.0' exited with status 'KILLED'. Check the logs
```

The logs:

```
Please see the attached cause exception "Unable to register procedure, because the name `example.index` is already in use.".
```

Any help,, please

Comment: Have you done some modification on the project ? Did you deploy twice the jar with a different name ? Do you have an other plugin that defines the procedure `example.index` ?

Comment: I have not modified anything ,,

Comment: Does the `plugins` directory contain multiple jar files for the sample?

Comment: @ cybersam , yes I got it now, I dropped both jars that I got, so that is why there is duplication.